# Extrapolation of measurement data

Tags: data-mining

I would like to extrapolate the results of a measurement. Following picture shows the measurements results. The best I can do is that to calculate the average values for 10 measurement and I use it for approximation, but the error is too large. In the following figure the blue graph is for measurement and the red graph is the average for 10 steps of measurement. The dots show the measurement points.
Does any one knows a better method for extrapolation so that one can get a smaller error?

[image]

Comment: ARIMA models would be well suited to this. You will need a good stats package to fit it though. I expect there are free ones, maybe someone else will respond with a suggestion.

Comment: How far out do you want to extrapolate? You have somewhat noisy data. Have you considered using a median filter? You could probably fit a polynomial to the results of the filter.